# Keycloak v23.0.3 Issue: Invalid Email Address Error During Password Reset with '+' Character

Tags: node.js, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I'm currently experiencing an issue with Keycloak version 23.0.3 in my project. Initially, I created an user with the email address arosu1@gmail.com. After receiving the confirmation email from Keycloak, I successfully logged in.

Later, I created a new user using the email address arosu1+1@gmail.com. The sign-up and login processes were completed successfully. It's important to note that the sign-up confirmation emails are being sent to the arosu1@gmail.com address.

The problem arises when attempting to reset the password for the user with the email address arosu1+1@gmail.com using Keycloak's forgotten password API. Despite the email already existing in the system, I'm receiving the message: "Invalid email address." Interestingly, removing the "+" character allows the password reset to work as expected.

I would appreciate any advice or insights on this matter.

Thank you.

Unfortunately, I have not come across any information on the websites.